# Showing question 1 by 1 in same window in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This is the project i'm currently working, an application to determine risk of someone in developing a heart disease in 10 year. I wonder how to implement the question section become showing 1 by 1 on the UI.r section instead from showing them all in the beginning of the app. Thank you in advance.

> UI.r

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",

                  titlePanel("Framingham Expert System"),


                  headerPanel(""),

                  sidebarLayout(
                          sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                                  h4("ENTER YOUR VALUES"),

                                  selectInput("sex",
                                              h6("Sex"),list("Male" = "male", "Female" = "female")),

                                  numericInput("age",
                                               h6("Age (year) ="),value = 30, min = 30, max = 80, step = 1),

                                  numericInput("TC",
                                               h6("Total cholesterol (mg/dL)"),value=200),

                                  numericInput("HDL",
                                               h6("HDL cholesterol (mg/dL)"),value=40),

                                  radioButtons("HTN",
                                               h6("Are you under treatment for hypertension?"),
                                               list("Yes" = 1, "No" = 0)),

                                  numericInput("SBP",
                                               h6("Systolic blood pressure levels (mm Hg)"),value = 120),

                                  radioButtons("smoke",
                                               h6("Are you a smoker?"),list("Yes" = 1, "No" = 0)),

                                  radioButtons("diabetes",
                                               h6("Are you diabetic?"),list("Yes" = 1, "No" = 0)),

                                  selectInput("CF",
                                              h6("Validitas Data"), list("Data Asal" = "data asal", "Hasil Test Lab < 3 bulan" = "hasil test lab < 3 bulan",
                                                                         "Hasil Test Lab > 3 Bulan" = "hasil test lab > 3 bulan", "Hasil Test Lab > 6 bulan" = "hasil test lab > 6 bulan",
                                                                         "Hasil Test Lab > 9 bulan" = "hasil test lab > 9 bulan"))
                          ),

                          mainPanel(
                                  h4("VALUE YOU ENTERED"),

                                  h6("Sex"),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("osex"),

                                  h6("Age"),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("oage"),

                                  h6("Total cholesterol"),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("oTC"),

                                  h6("HDL choletserol"),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("oHDL"),

                                  h6("Treated for Hypertension?"),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("oHTN"),

                                  h6("Systolic blood presure levels"),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("oSBP"),

                                  h6("Current smoker"),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("osmoke"),

                                  h6("Diabetes"),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("odiabetes"),

                                  h6("Validitas Data"),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("ocf"),
                                  br(),

                                  h4(strong("10 year CARDIOVASCULAR RISK SCORE % =")),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("ofram"),

                                  h4(strong("Classification Risk =")),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("num"),

                                  h4(strong("Certainty Factor % = ")),
                                  verbatimTextOutput("cf")
                          )
                  )

))
```

> Server.r

```
#server.R
library(shiny)
framingham <- function(sex,age,TC,HDL,HTN,SBP,smoke,diabetes){ 
        if (sex == "male") {
                bixi = 3.06117*log(age)+1.12370*log(TC)-0.93263*log(HDL)+1.93303*log(SBP)*(1-as.numeric(HTN))+1.99881*log(SBP)*as.numeric(HTN)+0.65451*as.numeric(smoke)+0.57367*as.numeric(diabetes)
                round((1-0.88936^exp(bixi-23.9802))*100,1)
        }
        else {
                bixi = 2.32888*log(age)+1.20904*log(TC)-0.70833*log(HDL)+2.76157*log(SBP)*(1-as.numeric(HTN))+2.82263*log(SBP)*as.numeric(HTN)+0.52873*as.numeric(smoke)+0.69154*as.numeric(diabetes)
                round((1-0.95012^exp(bixi-26.1931))*100,1)
        }}
shinyServer(
        function(input, output) {
                output$osex <- renderPrint(input$sex)
                output$oage <- renderPrint(input$age)
                output$oTC <- renderPrint(input$TC)
                output$oHDL <- renderPrint(input$HDL)
                output$oHTN <- renderPrint(input$HTN)
                output$oSBP <- renderPrint(input$SBP)
                output$osmoke <- renderPrint(input$smoke)
                output$odiabetes <- renderPrint(input$diabetes)
                output$ocf <- renderPrint(input$CF)
                output$ofram <- renderPrint({framingham(input$sex,input$age,input$TC,input$HDL,as.numeric(input$HTN),input$SBP,as.numeric(input$smoke),as.numeric(input$diabetes))})
                output$num <- renderPrint({
                        if (framingham(input$sex,input$age,input$TC,input$HDL,as.numeric(input$HTN),input$SBP,as.numeric(input$smoke),as.numeric(input$diabetes)) <= 5)
                        {
                                "Low"
                        }
                        else if (framingham(input$sex,input$age,input$TC,input$HDL,as.numeric(input$HTN),input$SBP,as.numeric(input$smoke),as.numeric(input$diabetes)) > 5.01 & framingham(input$sex,input$age,input$TC,input$HDL,as.numeric(input$HTN),input$SBP,as.numeric(input$smoke),as.numeric(input$diabetes)) <= 10)
                        {
                                "Medium"
                        }
                        else if (framingham(input$sex,input$age,input$TC,input$HDL,as.numeric(input$HTN),input$SBP,as.numeric(input$smoke),as.numeric(input$diabetes)) > 10.01)
                        {
                                "High"
                        }
                })
                output$cf <- renderPrint({
                        if (input$CF == "data asal")
                        {
                                (((62.5 / 100) * 0.47) * 100)
                        }
                        else if (input$CF == "hasil test lab < 3 bulan")
                        {
                                (((62.5 / 100) * 1) * 100) 
                        }
                        else if (input$CF == "hasil test lab > 3 bulan")
                        {
                                (((62.5 / 100) * 0.8) * 100) 
                        }
                        else if (input$CF == "hasil test lab > 6 bulan")
                        {
                                (((62.5 / 100) * 0.5) * 100) 
                        }
                        else if (input$CF == "hasil test lab > 9 bulan")
                        {
                                (((62.5 / 100) * 0.3) * 100) 
                        }
                })
        }

)
```

This is the image when the app run.
[App first run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c70u.png)

I want the question section, which on the left can be showed 1 by one. Instead giving them all in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI have tried in these manner. Hope this you are looking for..
Process...

[image]

UI.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyglide)


dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
   dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
         menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))
      )
   ),
   dashboardBody(
      useShinyalert(),
      tabItems(
         tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                 fluidRow(
                    column(6,
                           box("Questions",status = 'primary',solidHeader=TRUE,width = 12,
                               glide(
                                  height = "200px",
                                  screen(
                                     selectInput("sex","Sex",choices = c("Male","Female"))
                                  ),
                                  screen(

                                     numericInput("age", "Age(Year)", value = 20, min = 20)
                                  ),
                                  screen(
                                     numericInput("TC", "Total Cholesterol(mg/dl)", value = 200, min = 500)
                                    ),
                                  screen(
                                     numericInput("HDL", "THDL Cholesterol(mg/dl)", value = 200, min = 500)
                                  ),
                                  screen(
                                     radioButtons("HTN","Are you under treatment for hypertrnsion?", choices = c("Yes"=1,"No"=0))
                                  ),
                                  screen(
                                     numericInput("SBP", "Systolic Blood Pressure levels(mm Hg)", value = 200, min = 500)
                                  ),
                                  screen(
                                     radioButtons("smoke","Are you a smoker?", choices = c("Yes"=1,"No"=0))
                                  ),
                                  screen(
                                     radioButtons("diabetes","Are you a diabetic?", choices = c("Yes"=1,"No"=0))
                                  ),
                                  screen(
                                     selectInput("CF","Validtas Data",choices = list("Data Asal" = "data asal", "Hasil Test Lab < 3 bulan" = "hasil test lab < 3 bulan",
                                                                                       "Hasil Test Lab > 3 Bulan" = "hasil test lab > 3 bulan", "Hasil Test Lab > 6 bulan" = "hasil test lab > 6 bulan",
                                                                                       "Hasil Test Lab > 9 bulan" = "hasil test lab > 9 bulan"))
                                  )
                               )

                               )
                           ),
                    column(6,
                           box("Questions",status = 'primary',solidHeader=TRUE,width = 12,
                               h4("VALUE YOU ENTERED"),

                               h6("Sex"),
                               verbatimTextOutput("osex"),

                               h6("Age"),
                               verbatimTextOutput("oage"),

                               h6("Total cholesterol"),
                               verbatimTextOutput("oTC"),

                               h6("HDL choletserol"),
                               verbatimTextOutput("oHDL"),

                               h6("Treated for Hypertension?"),
                               verbatimTextOutput("oHTN"),

                               h6("Systolic blood presure levels"),
                               verbatimTextOutput("oSBP"),

                               h6("Current smoker"),
                               verbatimTextOutput("osmoke"),

                               h6("Diabetes"),
                               verbatimTextOutput("odiabetes"),

                               h6("Validitas Data"),
                               verbatimTextOutput("ocf"),
                               br(),

                               h4(strong("10 year CARDIOVASCULAR RISK SCORE % =")),
                               verbatimTextOutput("ofram"),

                               h4(strong("Classification Risk =")),
                               verbatimTextOutput("num"),

                               h4(strong("Certainty Factor % = ")),
                               verbatimTextOutput("cf")

                              )
                           )

                        )
                 )
      )
   )
)
```

Server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


shinyServer(function(input,output){

  framingham <- function(sex,age,TC,HDL,HTN,SBP,smoke,diabetes){ 
    if (sex == "male") {
      bixi = 3.06117*log(age)+1.12370*log(TC)-0.93263*log(HDL)+1.93303*log(SBP)*(1-as.numeric(HTN))+1.99881*log(SBP)*as.numeric(HTN)+0.65451*as.numeric(smoke)+0.57367*as.numeric(diabetes)
      round((1-0.88936^exp(bixi-23.9802))*100,1)
    }
    else {
      bixi = 2.32888*log(age)+1.20904*log(TC)-0.70833*log(HDL)+2.76157*log(SBP)*(1-as.numeric(HTN))+2.82263*log(SBP)*as.numeric(HTN)+0.52873*as.numeric(smoke)+0.69154*as.numeric(diabetes)
      round((1-0.95012^exp(bixi-26.1931))*100,1)
    }}

  output$osex <- renderPrint(input$sex)
  output$oage <- renderPrint(input$age)
  output$oTC <- renderPrint(input$TC)
  output$oHDL <- renderPrint(input$HDL)
  output$oHTN <- renderPrint(input$HTN)
  output$oSBP <- renderPrint(input$SBP)
  output$osmoke <- renderPrint(input$smoke)
  output$odiabetes <- renderPrint(input$diabetes)
  output$ocf <- renderPrint(input$CF)
  output$ofram <- renderPrint({framingham(input$sex,input$age,input$TC,input$HDL,as.numeric(input$HTN),input$SBP,as.numeric(input$smoke),as.numeric(input$diabetes))})
  output$num <- renderPrint({
     value<-framingham(input$sex,input$age,input$TC,input$HDL,as.numeric(input$HTN),input$SBP,as.numeric(input$smoke),as.numeric(input$diabetes))

    if (is.null(value)||value <= 5)
    {
      "Low"
    }
    else if (is.null(value)||value <= 10)
    {
      "Medium"
    }
    else if (is.null(value)||value > 10.01)
    {
      "High"
    }
  })
  output$cf <- renderPrint({
    if (is.null(input$CF)||input$CF == "data asal")
    {
      (((62.5 / 100) * 0.47) * 100)
    }
    else if (input$CF == "hasil test lab < 3 bulan")
    {
      (((62.5 / 100) * 1) * 100) 
    }
    else if (input$CF == "hasil test lab > 3 bulan")
    {
      (((62.5 / 100) * 0.8) * 100) 
    }
    else if (input$CF == "hasil test lab > 6 bulan")
    {
      (((62.5 / 100) * 0.5) * 100) 
    }
    else if (input$CF == "hasil test lab > 9 bulan")
    {
      (((62.5 / 100) * 0.3) * 100) 
    }
  })



})
```

Comment: its indeed like what i wanted to. I will try this one, in a moment

Answer (score 0):

One idea that jumps to mind is using {shinyjs} to dynamically show and hide elements.

Load the library, include `useShinyjs()` in your UI. You can then initialise elements as `hidden` and in the server programatically show/hide what you want.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  textInput("name", "Enter your name"),
  actionButton("submit", "Submit age"),
  hidden(
    sliderInput("age", "What is your age", value = 18, min = 16, max = 90)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    # do stuff
    # then show/hide
    hide("name")
    hide("submit")
    show("age")
  })

  observeEvent(input$age, {
    # do stuff
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT**

Further your comment. You don't have to show/hide inputs only you, this can be any element. Moreover, re-reading your question we could simplify this somewhat. Indeed as hinted in your comment the above would lead to a quiet a lot of dirty code.

Initialise hidden divs (sections) then show/hide them as you want.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(
    id = "section1",
    textInput("name", "Enter your name"),
    actionButton("section1btn", "Submit age")
  ),
  hidden(
    div(
      id = "section2",
      textInput("age", "What's ayour age"),
      textInput("x", "Another input x"),
      actionButton("section2btn", "Submit")
    )
  ),
  hidden(
    div(
      id = "section3",
      textInput("y", "Another input y"),
      textInput("z", "Another input z")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$section1btn, {
    # do stuff
    # then show/hide
    hide("section1")
    show("section2")
  })

  observeEvent(input$section2btn, {
    # do stuff
    hide("section2")
    show("section3")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: on the action button, did i need to mention all my param on that ?
sorry for asking, but im currently new on this language

Comment: No problem. I edited my question: hope this answers your question.

Comment: i will try this method first, i will let you know if its worked

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to wrap them into a 2 `column`?
You may need to use a `fluidRow()` statement, but it should work.

```
column(6,
   radioButtons("smoke", h6("Are you a smoker?"),list("Yes" = 1, "No" = 0)),
),
column(6,
   radioButtons("diabetes",h6("Are you diabetic?"),list("Yes" = 1, "No" = 0)),  
)
```

the max width is 12 and you can play with that to align the questions as you like.

Comment: already tried that one, but the fluidrow() statement didn't do anything

Comment: did you add `fluidRow` also for the other options? basically you would need 3 `fluidRow` (for keepin the options as they are now.

Comment: no i didnt, i only use 1 fluidrow() statement backthen. maybe this can help too, i will let you know in a moment